# How to check if an element is in a vector made of structs?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, compare

I created this struct:

```
struct topic_set
{
    string topic;
} topics;

vector<topic_set> subjects;
```

I want to create a function that returns true if the vector subjects already contains a topic. This is what I did (but it's wrong):

```
    bool contains(topic_set topic)
    {
        for(topics.i = 0; topics.i < subjects.size(); topics.i++)
            if(subjects[i] == topics.topic)
                 return true;
     }
```

What should I modify to make it work?

The purpose of the program is to create a virtual library where I can add as many books as I want. To create a book I have to add the name of the author, the title AND a set of topic. So there may be more than one topic for each book. I have to use three data structures (topic_set, book, library) and i can't change it.

Comment: Shouldn't your `contains` function take a `subjects` container as an argument?

Comment: You have better chances to get better answers if you provide more complete code. Based on what you provided, one assumes that you use `vector<topic_set` in the global namespace, which is not recommended in general (though for exercise maybe ok).

Comment: Most of the code you posted is irrelevant. You should remove all the book and library stuff. Your question is already confusing enough.

Answer (score 5):

The loop-less version would use [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
bool contains(topic_set src)
{
   auto iter = std::find_if(subjects.begin(), subjects.end(), 
               [&](const topic_set& ts){return ts.topic == src.topic;});
   return iter != subjects.end();
}
```

Also, you should really pass the `topic_set` by const reference, not by value:

```
bool contains(const topic_set& src)
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code does not even compile. `topics.i` should result in compile error, since `topic_set` does not have a member `i` (as required in `for` loop).

Correct syntax for such behaviour would be something like that

```
bool contains(topic_set topic)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < subjects.size(); ++i)
        if (subjects[i] == topic.topic)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

There are also some other issues (like passing parameter by const ref, using namespace std, global scope) which would probably be better explained at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -1):

There are a few things wrong with this code. Firstly, I'm not sure what the motivation was behind creating a struct named `topic_set` to hold only a single field `topic`. Your struct is for a single value not a set, and is not necessary at all. I would suggest having your `subjects` vector be a vector of strings, and modify your book struct to be as follows:

```
struct book
{
    string author;
    string title;
    string topic;
};
```

I also can't quite tell what you're trying to do with the `library` struct and the `Library` vector

Given the change from topic_set to string, your new, corrected function would look as follows:

```
bool contains(const string& topic)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < subjects.size(); ++i)
        if (subjects[i] == topic)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Also, do you want the ability to have duplicate entries in the subjects vector? Do you need constant time access to specific indices? If not, you might actually want `std::set` for this, which would make your `contains` look as follows:

```
bool contains(const string& topic) 
{
    return subjects.find(topic) != subjects.end();
}
```

Here's some documentation on std::set http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/

Comment: I have to use three data structures named topic_set, book and library. It's specified in the exercise.

Answer (score -1):

Might be cleaner to do something like the following:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using Topic = std::string;
using Topic_set = std::vector<Topic>;

struct Book {
    bool contains(const Topic& topic);
    std::string author;
    std::string title;
    Topic_set subjects;
};

using Library = std::vector<Book>;

int main()
{
    Library library{
        {"Author Name1","Book Title1",{"Algebra","Calculus"}},
        {"Author Name2","Book Title2",{"Astronony","Calculus"}},
        {"Author Name3","Book Title3",{"Algebra","Calculus"}},
        {"Author Name4","Book Title4",{"Astronony","Calculus"}}
    };
    std::cout << "The following books are about Algebra:\n";
    for (auto book : library)
        if (book.contains("Algebra")) std::cout << book.title << '\n';
    return 0;
}

bool Book::contains(const Topic& topic)
{
    return std::any_of(subjects.begin(),subjects.end(),[&topic](const Topic& t) { return topic == t; });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I removed `topics` it in that case. Its usage is not correct in your case.

I changed your function. It iterates over the subjects topics one by one and compares each with the topic given as a parameter. When an equality is found it returns true, otherwise false.

```
struct topic_set
{
    string topic;
};

vector<topic_set> subjects;

struct book
{
    string author;
    string title;
    struct topic_set; //i tried using topic_set topic here, but didnt work
 };

vector<book> books;

struct library
{
    struct book;
};

vector<library> Library;

bool contains(topic_set topic)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < subjects.size(); i++)
        if ( subjects[i].topic == topic.topic )
             return true;
    return false;
}
```

I won't go further, since I assume you are a beginner. But you should know that there is still a way to go if you want to write *proper* C++ code.

The other answers show some of the advanced concepts, though I think it's maybe too early for you now.